# Min and Max heap in Java and Scala

Tags: java, scala, heap

After doing some digging here is what I understood-

Java default Priority Queue is a min heap but Scala default Priority Queue is a max heap.
Is this correct?
Why is the implementation different in scala, it just causes more confusion in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java `PriorityQueue` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)) defines the highest-priority item to be the one with the *lowest* sorting order, so a min-heap is the logical choice of data structure.

The Scala `PriorityQueue` (see [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html)) apparently defines the highest-priority item to be the   *highest-sorting*, so a max-heap is the logical choice of data structure.

If you're asking why it is that highest priority means lowest-sorting in Java and highest-sorting is Scala, only the developers of the respective language libraries can answer that.